# No more USB001 port available in W7 Desktop HP

Tags: windows-7

On my HP Desktop PC the HP P1006 USB printer stopped working and the "What's Printing" showed an error.  Cancelled the jobs queued there.  Restarted the PC and still no print.  Deleted the printer and all USB devices, and have removed all the USB lines under Device Manager USB Controllers.  Restarted the PC again and watch all the USB controllers re-establish themselves.  Plug in the P1006 printer, and the PC reports that it has found the P1006 printer and lists it in the USB Controllers list.  However, the PC never completes the print driver install.  There is a Listing in USB Controllers for USB Printing.  Tried downloading the print driver from HP, but when I run the routine and get to the portion where I have to select the print port, there is no USB001 virtual port available.  How do I get the USB001 port back?

Answer (score 0):

The problem revolves around Windows Updates.  Shortly after processing the latest updated this PC (but none of the other like models at our location) lost the ability to use the driver for the HP P1006 printer that was being used.  Before removing the printer from the Device Manager USB Controller list, you must go into Printer Management and remove any HP P1006 drivers listed there.  To do otherwise only results in Windows reverting to the old driver when it boots up again, and you get stuck chasing your tail.  So 1st delete the printer from the Devices and Printers Control Panel app, then go into Printer Managment (type Print into Windows search), find the drivers listed for you printer in question and delete them, The delete the USB support for you printer in Device Manager USB Controllers, and turn off your printer.  Then restart your PC, and when fully booted up, turn on the printer (or plug in the USB cable.  The system should find the printer type and place it in the Unspecified list in Devices and Printers, and then find (Windows Update) the latest Windows tagged printer driver if you have internet access.  Poof USB001 shows up again.